# ifconfig-changes not saved after reboot - In CENTOS ssh? <Red Hat>

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, network-interface

I configured manually the eno2 interface with static ip and ifconfig file for that eno2 configuration is : (vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno2 ) < Red Hat >

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_MODE=none
DEVICE=eno2
NAME=eno2
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
NETMASK=255.255.254.0
IPADDR=10.63.1.50
GATEWAY=10.63.0.1
DEFROUTE=yes
```

then afterwards I save this script and what's written is saved ... if I got and do ping to 10.63.1.50 it shows me that eno2 is pinging and interface eno2 is up!

BUT , if I do reboot to my machine then all what I configured is gone and need to do again manually what I've already done .. How do I save ifconfig-changes of eno2 after reboot - In CENTOS ssh environment ?!

Thanks alot for any suggestion and it's weird why ifconfig configuration keeps changes after each reboot ..I need to keep eno2 ip configuration interface as static , means after reboot there's no need to re-configure again ifconfig eno2 script ..

Comment: Which version of CentOS are you running? Do you have NetworkManager service up an running? What command do you use to bring eno2 interface up and running?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your RH/CentOS version, you may need to install `yum install network-scripts` and `systemctl enable network` if you still want to use the old way of configuring networking.

Furthermore, you may want to disable the NetworkManager, if you desire to configure every network related aspect manually:

```
# systemctl mask NetworkManager.service
# systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
# systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
```

As alternative, you could use `NM_CONTROLLED=no` within the configuration file to explicitly disable NetworkManager control for this specific device only.

To [configure a network interface **without** using NetworkManager](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configuring_ip_networking_with_ifcg_files):

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno2`:

```
DEVICE=eno2
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
PREFIX=24
IPADDR=10.63.1.50
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```